# Loading ResistanceGA package - problem creating vignettes LatTex failed to compile - when attempting to load

Tags: latex, tinytex

I attempt to load this package here
devtools::install_github("wpeterman/ResistanceGA", build_vignettes = TRUE)

But it fails at the last part
I do have tinytex package installed and running.
Please any advice ?   Thank you.  Carlos

── R CMD build ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\Carl Bedson\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpU1IIM6\remotes361c3c8f67ef\wpeterman-ResistanceGA-9897bf4/DESCRIPTION' ...
─  preparing 'ResistanceGA': (339ms)
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  installing the package to build vignettes
E  creating vignettes (38.2s)
--- re-building 'GettingStarted.Rmd' using rmarkdown
--- finished re-building 'GettingStarted.Rmd'

--- re-building 'Julia_Guide.Rmd' using rmarkdown
--- finished re-building 'Julia_Guide.Rmd'

--- re-building 'ResistanceGA.Rmd' using rmarkdown
Warning in system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
'"pdflatex"' not found
Error: processing vignette 'ResistanceGA.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
LaTeX failed to compile C:/Users/Carl Bedson/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpiCkEyu/Rbuild2a481b9a62a0/ResistanceGA/vignettes/ResistanceGA.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
--- failed re-building 'ResistanceGA.Rmd'

SUMMARY: processing the following file failed:
'ResistanceGA.Rmd'

Error: Vignette re-building failed.
Execution halted
Error: Failed to install 'ResistanceGA' from GitHub:
! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed

> 

Expected it to load ResistanceGA package - but it failed

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this by disabling the need to write the Latex file which build the Vignetter and the package then loaded fine